# How to customize an unauthorized response on Spring WebFlux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I'm starting a new project using Spring Webflux, but now i can't figure it out how to handle 401 responses.

Usually i handle it by `@ExceptionHandler({ InvalidTokenException.class, AuthenticationException.class })` on Spring Boot with Tomcat.

Here is my Controller Advice:

```
    @ExceptionHandler({ InvalidTokenException.class, AuthenticationException.class })
    public ResponseEntity<Mono<ApiResponse>> handleError401(ServerHttpRequest request, Exception e)   {

        return new ResponseEntity<Mono<ApiResponse>>(
          Mono.just(
                  ApiResponse
                  .builder()
                  .success(false)
                  .code(ResponseType.AUTHENTICATION_ERROR.getCode())
                  .responseType(ResponseType.AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)
                  .message("login failed")
                  .build()
          ),
          HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED
        );
    }
```

Edit:

I also tried this, but no exception was thrown

```
    @ExceptionHandler({ Exception.class })
    public ResponseEntity<Mono<ApiResponse>> handleError401(ServerHttpRequest request, Exception e)   {

        return new ResponseEntity<Mono<ApiResponse>>(
          Mono.just(
                  ApiResponse
                  .builder()
                  .success(false)
                  .code(ResponseType.AUTHENTICATION_ERROR.getCode())
                  .responseType(ResponseType.AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)
                  .message("login failed")
                  .build()
          ),
          HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to temporarily put parent `Exception.class` in `@ExceptionHandler` to check if you are getting the intended exception type. Sometimes it gets wrapped into some other type of exception such as `UndeclaredThrowableException`.

Comment: I've make the change, but i haven't success... No exception was thrown. I'll keep seeking for a solution. Regards!